# Javascript/Moment.js generate Unix timestamp for today, 10:00PM etc

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How do I generate the Unix timestamp for an hour today or tomorrow using Moment.js or vanilla JS? For example:

1. Today, 22:00
2. Tomorrow, 03:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `moment().startOf('hour').hours(22).unix()`
2. `moment().add(1, 'days').startOf('hour').hours(3).unix()`

Comment: Does this generate the timestamp in seconds, as opposed to milliseconds? The other Moment.js APIs seem to return the time in milliseconds?

Comment: @AmalAntony have you taken the time to look at the documentation for `.unix()` even?

Comment: @Pointy Yes I have.

Comment: OK [well it's pretty clear that `.unix()` returns seconds.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/)